# get datatype of column using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We are reading data from MongoDB `Collection`. `Collection` column has two different values (e.g.: `(bson.Int64,int) (int,float)` ).

I am trying to get a datatype using pyspark.

My problem is some columns have different datatype.

Assume `quantity` and `weight` are the columns

```
quantity           weight
---------          --------
12300              656
123566000000       789.6767
1238               56.22
345                23
345566677777789    21
```

Actually we didn't defined data type for any column of mongo collection.

When I query to the count from `pyspark dataframe`

```
dataframe.count()
```

I got exception like this

```
"Cannot cast STRING into a DoubleType (value: BsonString{value=&apos;200.0&apos;})"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Without providing what you have tried and not worked, it is highly doubtful that anyone here would be able to help you. Please check 'How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example' https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', -1) # to prevent truncating of columns in jupyter

def count_column_types(spark_df):
    """Count number of columns per type"""
    return pd.DataFrame(spark_df.dtypes).groupby(1, as_index=False)[0].agg({'count':'count', 'names': lambda x: " | ".join(set(x))}).rename(columns={1:"type"})
```

Example output in jupyter notebook for a spark dataframe with 4 columns:

```py
count_column_types(my_spark_df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 126):

*Your question is broad, thus my answer will also be broad.*

To get the data types of your `DataFrame` columns, you can use `dtypes` i.e :

```
>>> df.dtypes
[('age', 'int'), ('name', 'string')]
```

This means your column `age` is of type `int` and `name` is of type `string`.

Comment: Would you care updating your question with your information. It's unclear what you are asking @Sreenuvasulu

Comment: My columns have different data types here too.

Comment: Please don't post information like this in the comment box. This is not readable. And take some time writing your question.

Comment: This is a complete different issue from what you have asked. Would you care adding some reproducible example ?

Comment: can you look into weight column,it has two different datatype

Comment: I'll not look into your question unless you provide the information @desertnaut asked for. You had a question which I have answered and now the question evolved into something completely different and you make no effort in writing the question correctly. Please review your question according the guidelines discussed in the comments.

Answer (score 36):

For anyone else who came here looking for an answer to the exact question in the post title (i.e. the data type of a single column, not multiple columns), I have been unable to find a simple way to do so.

Luckily it's trivial to get the type using `dtypes`:

```
def get_dtype(df,colname):
    return [dtype for name, dtype in df.dtypes if name == colname][0]

get_dtype(my_df,'column_name')
```

(note that this will only return the first column's type if there are multiple columns with the same name)

Comment: More succinct: `dict(df.dtypes)[colname]`

Comment: This solution, although working of course, will give a potentially misleading IndexError, if the column is not found. It will also continue checking all columns, even if the column is already found.

    def get_dtype(df, col_name: str):
        for name, dtype in df.dtypes:
            if name == col_name:
                return type
        else:
            raise Exception("Column not found")

Answer (score 8):

I don't know how are you reading from mongodb, but if you are using the mongodb connector, the datatypes will be automatically converted to spark types. To get the spark sql types, just use schema atribute like this:

```
df.schema
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your actual data and your metadata have different types. The actual data is of type string while the metadata is double.

As a solution I would recommend you to recreate the table with the correct datatypes.

Answer (score 3):

[`df.dtypes`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dtypes.html) to get a list of `(colname, dtype)` pairs, ex.

```
[('age', 'int'), ('name', 'string')]
```

[`df.schema`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.schema.html) to get a schema as `StructType` of `StructField`, ex.

```
StructType(List(StructField(age,IntegerType,true),StructField(name,StringType,true)))
```

[`df.printSchema()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.printSchema.html) to get a tree view of the schema, ex.

```
root
 |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: To get the datatype of a column in a dataframe, we can also use the apply function (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.html#apply-java.lang.String-) of StructType object: `df.schema.apply("column-name-here").dataType`. This will give the data type as a DataType object (https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [('A+','good','Robert',550,3000),
  ('A+','good','Robert',450,4000),
  ('A+','bad','James',300,4000),
  ('A','bad','Mike',100,4000),
  ('B-','not bad','Jenney',250,-1)
]

columns = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Temp-Example').getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = columns)
df.printSchema()


# root
#  |-- A: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- B: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- C: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- D: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- E: long (nullable = true)
```

you can get datatype by simple code

```
# get datatype 
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

data_types = defaultdict(list)
for entry in df.schema.fields:
    data_types[str(entry.dataType)].append(entry.name)

pd.DataFrame(list((i,len(data_types[i])) for i in data_types) , columns = ["datatype","Nums"])

#   datatype    Nums
# 0 StringType()    3
# 1 LongType()  2
```

Answer (score -14):

I am assuming you are looking to get the data type of the data you read.

input_data = [Read from Mongo DB operation]

You can use

```
type(input_data)
```

to inspect the data type

Comment: This doesn't apply here. It's pyspark specific.

Comment: this type funtion used in python not applicable in pyspark