# Is there a way to get the column data type in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Has been discussed that the way to find the column datatype in pyspark is using df.dtypes [get datatype of column using pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033315/get-datatype-of-column-using-pyspark). The problem with this is that for datatypes like an array or struct you get something like `array<string>` or `array<integer>`.

Question: Is there a native way to get the pyspark data type? Like `ArrayType(StringType,true)`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just use `schema`:

```
df.schema[column_name].dataType
```

Comment: `dict(df.dtypes)[column_name]` also works (thanks @RobinL). But note you'll get the datatype as a string name rather than the formal type name; e.g., `timestamp` vs `TimestampType`.

Comment: @snark - you mean a `str` instead of a type object, like `TimestampType()`? Thanks for the comment, in the end I might want the string ;)

Comment: Yes, as a string. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html#DataType.typeName