# Data Type of a PySpark Column

Tags: pyspark

If Column c is passed into the function, how can I determine its data type when the PySpark DataFrame is not passed in as a parameter?

```
def dosomething(c: Column):
  # Code when c is StringType
  # Code when c is DateType
```

I have access to SparkSession.getActiveSession() but not sure if it helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get datatype of column using pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033315/get-datatype-of-column-using-pyspark)

Comment: Hi @samkart , it does not. The article you gave used df.schema.  In my case, I am evaluating an expression. E.g. ```eval("IIF(ISNULL(c), F.lit(1), F.lit(0))")```. As you see, only Column ``c``` is the input parameter to Function ```ISNULL```, and Column ```ISNULL(c)``` is the input parameter to Function ```IIF```, and there is no ```df``` the DataFrame.

Comment: Both Function ```ISNULL``` and ```IIF``` are functions created in my project; they are not from PySpark.

Comment: one of the answers uses `df.dtypes`. looks like that can be useful to your needs, but you'd need to adapt that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is more about whether or not you can get the datatype of a column by just passing the column name into function. I don't think you can do that unless you create the dataframe in the function. See the example below.

If I comment out the line that creates spark_df, the code will fail with the following error - "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'spark_df' referenced before assignment"

```
def trial(col_name):
  spark_df=spark.createDataFrame(stock1_prices)

  if spark_df.dtypes[0][1]=="double":
    spark_df=spark_df.withColumn("checking",col(col_name).cast(StringType()))
    return spark_df
ok=trial("value")
print(ok)
```

Comment: the input is a Column, not a str. I am alright if the answer is "not possible". I am in this situation, and i want to confirm that the only way to get the datatype is first to going out of the way to get the DataFrame for df.dtypes or df.schema.

Comment: However, part of me feels less brilliant when I cannot get the datatype although I have the Column object in my hands.